# I Con't Add Multi Google Account Using Laravel 10 and Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I Try To Create Multi Google Services Using Laravel 10 And Socialite;

In Services.php I add :

```
'sign_in_google' => [
    'client_id' => env('SIGN_IN_GOOGLE_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('SIGN_IN_GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/sign-in/google/callback'
],
'sign_up_google' => [
    'client_id' => env('SIGN_UP_GOOGLE_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('SIGN_UP_GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/sign-up/google/callback'
]
```

When I Try To Use It By Controller:

```
public function signInRedirect() {
    return Socialite::driver('sign_in_google') -> redirect();
}
```

It's Show Error:

```
Driver [user_sign_in_google] not supported.
```

Comment: I don't think you can change the driver name, you have to use driver names that socialite supports, such as `google`,`facebook`,`twitter`, etc. Otherwise, you may need to create a custom provider ( Use this as reference [Socialite Providers](https://socialiteproviders.com/) )

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a custom driver name that isn't supported by Socialite, you can not use **driver** method.

You need to use **buildProvider** method, like below:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\GoogleProvider;

public function signInRedirect()
{
    $driver = Socialite::buildProvider(
        GoogleProvider::class, config('services.sign_in_google')
    );

    return $driver->redirect();
}
```

Comment: I Try It Put It's Show Error "Illegal offset type in isset or empty"

Comment: Can you show me more details about errors?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/cY3eplA90Om2

Comment: I edited my answer. I tested on my local, it's ok